# Finding recurring items in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, duplicates, nsuserdefaults

I am having a hard time understanding how to go about finding the values that repeat more than once. I'm just not understanding from the code below how to go about getting the duplicate values. thanks for any help!!

```
[appDelegate.scannedNumbers addObject:result];
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:appDelegate.scannedNumbers forKey:@"scannedNumbers"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
[BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"After writing scannedNumbers: %@" [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"scannedNumbers"]]];
```

Comment: This code seems irrelevant to what you're trying to do... What have you actually done to try to find duplicate numbers?

Comment: HI,Right now it logs all the scannedNumbers but not sure how to pick out the scannedNumbers that are displayed more than once? thanks for your time

Comment: Have you thought of an approach and tried it? Have you done a Google search to find an approach?

Comment: hi, yes i have been googling like crazy but i'm just not getting it. Lots of examples that don't seem to help me see it clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Setting a default has no effect on the value returned by the objectForKey: method if the same key exists in a domain that precedes the application domain in the search list.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)

You have to check if the key already exists before you will set another object for the same key.